# In CSS, how to toggle the tab color if it was selected (without using javascript)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to toggle the tab header color when it was selected.
I know it is tuff to do without javascript but I need it without javascript.
I searched in SO but I can't absorb it from their question.

This is my CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#tabs-1,#tabs-2,#tabs-3,#tabs-4,#tabs-5,#tabs-6{
    min-height: 350px;
}

table{
border-collapse: separate;
}

table td {
    width: 195px;
}

table tr .td-label {
    text-align: left;
    height:25px; 
    width: 280px;
}

table h3 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#330066;
}

#tabs li{
background-color:orange;
}
#tabs li:hover{
background-color:white;
}

#tabs li[tabindex="0"] a {
    background-color:white;
}

</style>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="demo">
        <h2>Tab Details</h2>

        <div style="height: 20px;">
            <label style="font-size: 12px">${msg}</label>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs" style="width: 790px;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1"><spring:message code="Tab1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2"><spring:message code="Tab2" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3"><spring:message code="Tab3" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4"><spring:message code="Tab4" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5"><spring:message code="Tab5" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6"><spring:message code="Tab6" /></a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>
</div>
```

Toggle the tab colors without using javascript coding.

Comment: `#tabs li a:visited`...?

Comment: css does not have a selected state, which is why this is always done using javascript, assuming you want to change tabs on the client, and not using server code.

Comment: Agree with archer. You can not have selected state with CSS. You have to add some of javascript here to keep the state of selected tab if you want to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
li[tabindex="0"] a{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Currently opened tab has attribute `tabindex="0"`

so we `li[tabindex="0"] a` we use `li` with `tabindex="0"` containing `a` tag change it's background-color

and all other tabs have attribute `tabindex="-1"`

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @Tushar attribute selector is fine, but how to set tabindex value on selecting a tab?

Comment: As per your link, how come the tabindex value will change automatically to "-1".Thanks for the link it is very helpful!

Comment: @TusharGupta : please look my edited question have your code but i dont know where it went wrong.In my html code, there are too many divs, may is it a problem?